# Backbone Collection.add doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am building a simple to-do application in backbone.
my html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>back bone</title>
<script src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/backbone.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<h2>Total Things Todo: <div id="no-todo"> 0 </div></h2>
<ul id="todo-list" class="unstyled">
</ul>
<div>
<button class="btn" id="add-todo"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add Todo</button>
</div>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and my backbone code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
        id: 0,
        text:null,
        completed: false
    });
    var Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:Todo,
        initialize: function(models, options) {
            this.on("add",options.view.addTodoLi);
        }
    });
    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("body"),
        initialize: function() {
            this.todos = new Todos(null,//[{id: 0,completed: false,text: "helo"},{id: 1,completed: false,text: "bye"}],
                {view: this });
        },
        events: {
            "click #add-todo": "addTodo"
        },
        addTodo: function() {
            var todo_name = prompt("What do you have to do?");
            var todo_model = new Todo({id: 0,completed: false,text: todo_name});
            this.todos.add(todo_model);
            console.log("todos",this.todos.toJSON(),
                todo_name,todo_model.toJSON());
        },
        addTodoLi: function(model){
            $("#todo-list").append("<li><div class='done-false'><input type='checkbox'/>"+model.get("text")+"</div></li>");
        }
    });
    var appview =  new AppView;
});
```

The problem is simple, for some reason `.add` function on the `this.todos` is not working after the first time. The `add` event is also triggered just once .It is as if the collection has become immutable. Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The collection simply prevents you from adding models that have the same `id`. If you were to add models with different `id`s everything should work just fine. In your case if you really don't intend to manage the ids by yourself you could omit them upon model instantiation and have backbone generate them for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I just hope they had given me some warning as to the special meaning of `id`, or thrown an error/exception. In the console it was as if every thing was working fine.

Comment: isn't Backbone supposed to check cid when id is blank?

Comment: Found the answer to my predicament- If ID is 'undefined', then the collection can keep on adding other models with undefined IDs as well. But if they are "" (empty string), then the addition is prevented.